# Python console input from html form using django

Tags: python, html, django, database

I have a personality analysis python script, but I want to make it runs in HTML and get the input form from the HTML page, and the shows the result back in the HTML page. I already use a Django framework to run HTML pages. But I don't know how to connect it with a python script. I have attached the python script.

```
    #  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import os
import pickle
import re
import string
from collections import Counter

import pandas as pd
import tweepy
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import *
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from unidecode import unidecode

ckey = '...'
csecret = '...'
atoken = '...'
asecret = '...'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

emoticons_str = r"""
    (?:
        [:=;] # Eyes
        [oO\-]? # Nose (optional)
        [D\)\]\(\]/\\OpP] # Mouth
    )"""

emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                           u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                           u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                           u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                           u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                           "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)

regex_str = [
    emoticons_str,
    r'<[^>]+>',  # HTML tags
    r'(?:@[\w_]+)',  # @-mentions
    r"(?:\#+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)",  # hash-tags
    r'http[s]?://(?:[a-z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&amp;+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]))+',  # URLs

    r'(?:(?:\d+,?)+(?:\.?\d+)?)',  # numbers
    r"(?:[a-z][a-z'\-_]+[a-z])",  # words with - and '
    r'(?:[\w_]+)',  # other words
    r'(?:\S)'  # anything else
]

tokens_re = re.compile(r'(' + '|'.join(regex_str) + ')', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
emoticon_re = re.compile(r'^' + emoticons_str + '$', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)


def tokenize(s):
    return tokens_re.findall(s)


def preprocess(s, lowercase=False):
    tokens = tokenize(s)
    if lowercase:
        tokens = [token if emoticon_re.search(token) else token.lower() for token in tokens]
    return tokens


def preproc(s):
    # s=emoji_pattern.sub(r'', s) # no emoji
    s = unidecode(s)
    POSTagger = preprocess(s)
    # print(POSTagger)

    tweet = ' '.join(POSTagger)
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(tweet)
    # filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]
    filtered_sentence = []
    for w in POSTagger:
        if w not in stop_words:
            filtered_sentence.append(w)
    # print(word_tokens)
    # print(filtered_sentence)
    stemmed_sentence = []
    stemmer2 = SnowballStemmer("english", ignore_stopwords=True)
    for w in filtered_sentence:
        stemmed_sentence.append(stemmer2.stem(w))
    # print(stemmed_sentence)

    temp = ' '.join(c for c in stemmed_sentence if c not in string.punctuation)
    preProcessed = temp.split(" ")
    final = []
    for i in preProcessed:
        if i not in final:
            if i.isdigit():
                pass
            else:
                if 'http' not in i:
                    final.append(i)
    temp1 = ' '.join(c for c in final)
    # print(preProcessed)
    return temp1


def getTweets(user):
    csvFile = open('user.csv', 'a', newline='')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    try:
        for i in range(0, 4):
            tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=user, count=1000, include_rts=True, page=i)
            for status in tweets:
                tw = preproc(status.text)
                if tw.find(" ") == -1:
                    tw = "blank"
                csvWriter.writerow([tw])
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print("Failed to run the command on that user, Skipping...")
    csvFile.close()


username = input("Please Enter Twitter Account handle: ")
getTweets(username)
with open('user.csv', 'rt') as f:
    csvReader = csv.reader(f)
    tweetList = [rows[0] for rows in csvReader]
os.remove('user.csv')
with open('newfrequency300.csv', 'rt') as f:
    csvReader = csv.reader(f)
    mydict = {rows[1]: int(rows[0]) for rows in csvReader}

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=mydict, min_df=1)
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(tweetList).toarray()
df = pd.DataFrame(x)

model_IE = pickle.load(open("BNIEFinal.sav", 'rb'))
model_SN = pickle.load(open("BNSNFinal.sav", 'rb'))
model_TF = pickle.load(open('BNTFFinal.sav', 'rb'))
model_PJ = pickle.load(open('BNPJFinal.sav', 'rb'))

answer = []
IE = model_IE.predict(df)
SN = model_SN.predict(df)
TF = model_TF.predict(df)
PJ = model_PJ.predict(df)

b = Counter(IE)
value = b.most_common(1)
print(value)
if value[0][0] == 1.0:
    answer.append("I")
else:
    answer.append("E")

b = Counter(SN)
value = b.most_common(1)
print(value)
if value[0][0] == 1.0:
    answer.append("S")
else:
    answer.append("N")

b = Counter(TF)
value = b.most_common(1)
print(value)
if value[0][0] == 1:
    answer.append("T")
else:
    answer.append("F")

b = Counter(PJ)
value = b.most_common(1)
print(value)
if value[0][0] == 1:
    answer.append("P")
else:
    answer.append("J")
mbti = "".join(answer)
print(mbti)
```

I want to take the input of the variable
`username = input("Please Enter Twitter Account handle: ")`
from the HTML form rather than console.
and show the output of the variable
`mbti = "".join(answer)`
`print(mbti)`
on the HTML page also